# MatrixGrid Control (non sequential Y-Axis Values)

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd

Another question, regarding this control.

My Y-Axis (rows) are filled with User data. I use the UserReference as Value (*Y-Axis Value Field Specifier*) and UserName as Title (*Y-Axis Title Field Specifier*).

Then, I fill the MatrixGrid in the Load Event.

My problem is that, as UserReference is not a sequential number, the data messes up and gets misplaced on the grid.

Example:
These instructions...

```
Event Grid1.Load

   &diaFrom = 1
   &pessoaFrom = 1
   &TaskRef = 'day:1 - per:1'
   LOAD

   &diaFrom = 2
   &pessoaFrom = 1
   &TaskRef = 'day:2 - per:1'
   LOAD

   &diaFrom = 3
   &pessoaFrom = 20
   &TaskRef = 'day:3 - per:20'
   LOAD

   &diaFrom = 5
   &pessoaFrom = 400
   &TaskRef = 'day:5 - per:400'
   LOAD

Endevent
```

...will result in this (notice that the person #20 and #400 records are misplaced):
[image]

This problem will not occur if the Y-Axis values are sequential. In this example, data is being placed on the correct column (Date), because the Value "Day" is sequential. 
Is this how the control works (only with sequential Values)? Or is it possible to user non-sequential values and I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

That is the way it is supposed to work. By design the axes are treated as linear scales.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is an issue of the control, or the way it is supposed to work.

I had to add "unnecessary" complexity to my structure, by adding a &UserSequentialNr variable, that will identify the Person on the Grid (instead of the already existing &personReference).

Now, both &Day and &UserSequentialNr are sequential (1,2,3,4...) and the problem is "solved" - everything is placed correctly on the grid.